# Inherited class methods with different signatures in python

Tags: python, class, abstract, mypy, python-typing

Let's consider the following code snippet:

```py
class A:
    def foo(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

class B(A):
    def foo(self) -> None:
        print("I'm B(A)")

class C(A):
    def foo(self, x: int) -> None:
        print(f"I'm C(A), x={x}")

bob = B()
bob.foo()

charly = C()
charly.foo(4)
```

When ran, it provides the expected result:

```
I’m B(A)
I’m C(A), x=4
```

However mypy is raising an error:

```
$ mypy subclass.py
subclass.py:10: error: Signature of « foo » incompatible with supertype « A » [override]
subclass.py:10: note: Superclass:
subclass.py:10: note: def foo(self) → None
subclass.py:10: note: Subclass:
subclass.py:10: note: def foo(self, x: int) → None
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Is that a bad design? What would be a good alternative, other than simply removing the abstract method from the parent class?

Comment: _"Is that a bad design?"_ Yes, it is not type safe, as mypy is telling you. Some function that takes an instance of `A` and calls its `foo` method, expects it to be callable without arguments. An instance of `C` is also an instance of `A`. But passing an instance of `C` to that function would cause an error because `C.foo` cannot be called without arguments. Subtypes must never be stricter in their preconditions. ([LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle))

Answer (score 1):

This may lead to hints misbehaviour as if you type hint your model with TypeVar like

```
T = TypeVar("T", bound=A)

instance: T = C()  # this may be more complex, e.g. function arg
instance.  # IDE suggests plain foo() without args
```

[image: PyCharm Suggestion]

Answer (score 1):

You can always use `args` and `kwargs` to show that the function can take any number of arguments and it's up to a child class implementation to decide the number of arguments and their names.

```py
class A:
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

class B(A):
    def foo(self) -> None:
        print("I'm B(A)")

class C(A):
    def foo(self, x: int) -> None:
        print(f"I'm C(A), x={x}")
```

Mypy should accept it.